# How do I average a sentiment score for a day with multiple texts?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, tm

I am doing a text sentiment analysis in R using the tm package. I have scraped news articles from Reuters and gave them a variable name according to their date. I added a,b,c etc. to indicate multiple articles per day, like this:

art170411a
art170411b
art170411c
art170410a
...
...

I then run a standard positive/negative terms analysis which gives me the sentiment score per article. My question is: how do I average these scores so that I get a sentiment score per day?

I have a VCorpus containing my 2000+ articles over 3 years. Every article has a date stamp. For the matching with the positive/negative terms I have converted my Corpus to a list and then a bag of words like this:

```
corp_list <- lapply(corp, FUN = paste, collapse=" ")
corp_bag <- str_split(corp_list, pattern = "\\s+")
```

I have the final score in two formats:

```
score_naive_list <- lapply(corp_bag, function(x) { sum(!is.na(match(x, pos))) - sum(!is.na(match(x, neg)))})

score_naive <- unlist(lapply(corp_bag, function(x) { sum(!is.na(match(x, pos))) - sum(!is.na(match(x, neg)))}))
```

So my question: how do I average the multiple sentiment scores into a one day score?

Comment: does `meta(corp,"datetimestamp")` give you an array of timestamps (or a single column data.frame) ? and if so can you give me `meta(corp,"datetimestamp")[1]` ?

Comment: This is the output:
$art140501a.txt
[1] "2017-06-07 14:30:29 GMT"

Comment: Another way might be to compile the texts from the different articles into one, and then make the bag of words from the compiled texts. Would that work?

Comment: you just gave the first element, but you actually obtain an array right ?

Comment: Correct. It gives this output for every article in the Corpus

Answer (score 0):

I redid my answer with reproducible data, once you get your data sorted this should work just fine.

```
library(tm)
reut21578 <- system.file("texts", "crude", package = "tm")
corp <- VCorpus(DirSource(reut21578),readerControl = list(reader = readReut21578XMLasPlain))

timestamps <- meta(reuters,"datetimestamp")
days <- sapply(timestamps,strftime,format="%Y-%m-%d")
pos <- c("good","excellent","positive","effective")
neg <- c("bad","terrible","negative")

corp_list <- lapply(corp, FUN = paste, collapse=" ")
daily_bows <- aggregate(corp_list ~ days,data.frame(corp_list = unlist(corp_list),days = days),FUN=paste,collapse = " ")
corp_bag <- str_split(daily_bows$corp_list, pattern = "\\s+")

score_string <- function(x){
  sum(!is.na(match(x, pos))) - sum(!is.na(match(x, neg)))
}
daily_bows$scores <- sapply(corp_bag,score_string)
print(daily_bows[,c("days","scores")])

# days scores
# 1 1987-02-26      3
# 2 1987-03-01      1
# 3 1987-03-02      1
```

Comment: I'm not so good at blind coding so please do a sanity check at each operation and tell me what error or weird thing you get

Comment: Your second line gives me this error message:  

Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x, tz = tz) : 
do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Comment: try now, I changed it

Comment: It works now. But the third line gives a very large error. What I have also noticed is that the time stamp is the same for every article. It is always 2017-06-07: the day I scraped, not the day the article was posted. I am very sorry, I thought it would give the day of the article

Comment: this should really work now :). Though it'll give only one row until your date issus is sorted